# JS Задать дату в нужном формате ISO?

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

Подскажите, пожалуйста как сконвертировать формат даты из миллисекунд в `(ГГГГ-ММ-ДДТЧЧ: ММ: SSZ)` ? Вот на таком пример. На выходи необходима строка, что-то по типу "2021-04-29T15:10:09.000Z"

```js
const currentTime = new Date();
const currentDataPlusOneDay = currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate() + 1);

console.log("currentDataPlusOneDay = ", currentDataPlusOneDay);

const rightDataPlusOneDay = currentDataPlusOneDay.toLocaleDateString('en-US'); ///...Это как-то не так работает 

console.log("rightDataPlusOneDa =", rightDataPlusOneDa);
```

Comment: `.toISOString()` ?

Comment: currentDataPlusOneDay.toISOString(); /// Возвращает ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, возможно ещё кому-то будет полезно

```js
setCurrentDataPlusOneDay = () => {

  Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    let date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
  }
  const currentDataPlusOneDay1 = new Date().addDays(1);
  const tzoffset = (currentDataPlusOneDay1).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  const currentTimePlusOneDay = (new Date(currentDataPlusOneDay1 - tzoffset)).toISOString().slice(0, -1);

  return currentTimePlusOneDay;
}
console.log(" setCurrentDataPlusOneDay = ", setCurrentDataPlusOneDay());
```

Тут с учетом проблемы связанной с таймзоной

Answer (score 3):

```js
const currentTime = new Date();
const currentDataPlusOneDay = currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate() + 1);

console.log("currentDataPlusOneDay = ", currentDataPlusOneDay);
const rightDataPlusOneDay = currentTime.toISOString();
console.log("rightDataPlusOneDa =", rightDataPlusOneDay);
```

Comment: А как сделать что бы для currentDataPlusOneDay вывести дату в нужном формате ?

Comment: Так я вывел.... `setDate` не возвращает копию даты, оно меняет дату, на которой вызывалось.

Comment: Как преобразовать текущую дату плюс один день в нужный формат ?  `currentDataPlusOneDay.toISOString();` /// Это не отрабатывает насколько я понял поскольку метод уже работает с числом